# Does EXPO BackgoroundFecth dependencie for android app when app terminated will still work in the background?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

dare all,

I tried to use the code in the documentation https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/ for BackgroundFetch. but the problem was that the App didn't work on termination and it semi-worked when it went to the background(I managed to do BackgroundFetch even on app termination with expo eject but I much prefer to work with expo).
I didn't find in the documentation that says that the EXPO BackgoroundFecth for the Android app on termination won't work, only on ios.

I will appreciate any help and info I can get.